# How to use jQuery ajax to check if file exists in JS array?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array `urlResult` which collects the `href` attribute of all `a` elements on a component. Looks like:

[image]

All I need to do is use jQuery `$.ajax()` method to check against those URL's and in each callback do something if there is success or failure. So I was thinking of something like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: urlResult[i] // somehow use dynamic variable?
    type:'HEAD',
    error: function()
    {
        //file not exists
    },
    success: function()
    {
        //file exists
    }
});
```

I just need some guidance on how to dynamically include `urlResult` variable and pass each index to `url` property in ajax call.

Comment: `$.each()` can be used to iterate over an array.  https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each  Or you can use the native `forEach()`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Comment: Would you perhaps be the same person who posted this? Striking similarities, and even includes the `type: 'HEAD'` suggestion from that question's comments. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59472049/how-to-have-dynamic-value-in-url-property-in-ajax-call?noredirect=1#comment105122618_59472049

Comment: Please clarify the issue further. Why would you link to files that do not exist? If this is generated content via a Server-side Script, that content should not appear on the page.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) to loop over the array of hrefs, and then execute your code inside the loop

```js
const urlResult = ['www.google.com', 'www.test.com', 'www.demo.com', 'www.aaaa.net'];

urlResult.forEach((href) => {
  $.ajax({
    url: href,
    type: 'HEAD',
    error: function() {
      console.log('HREF was ' + href);
      console.log('error');
    },
    success: function() {
      console.log('HREF was ' + href);
      console.log('success');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following code.

```
$(function() {
  function checkFile(u) {
    var result = false;
    $.ajax({
      url: u
      type: "HEAD",
      success: function() {
        result = true;
      }
    });
    return result;
  }

  $.each(urlResult, function(i, v) {
    if (checkFile(v)) {
      // File exists, do the needful
    }
  });
});
```

Remember that `success` is only called when HTTP Status is `200`. I used `$.each()` to iterate over the Array.

> The `$.each()` function is not the same as `$(selector).each()`, which is used to iterate, exclusively, over a jQuery object. The `$.each()` function can be used to iterate over any collection, whether it is an object or an array. In the case of an array, the callback is passed an array index and a corresponding array value each time.

See More:

- https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/
- https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/